# Hive persmission denied error

Tags: permissions, hive

I have two ids us_id1 and us_id2, both ids are part of group alldev.
With us_id1 I can go and view all directories in HDFS, and I can execute all Hive commands

With us_id2 I can view all directories and log into hive.

But when I run a simple command like show databases; I get the following error.

`on database directory /datalake/sample_dev/metastore_db in READ ONLY mode
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient`

What is missing for us_id2?

Comment: you have not updated default metastore setting and your hive is using default derby metastore. Seems user us_id2 doesn't have enough permission to initiate "/datalake/sample_dev/metastore_db".

1- change the metastore_db permissions.

2- also check if "/datalake/sample_dev/metastore_db" has any lock(lck) file then remove it.

Comment: Rahul,You were correct I had to update default metastore setting for us_id2

Comment: mark question answered... :)